# passing multiple models from action to action and save all model at once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 5 classes:

1) `EmployeeMainTable.cs` (`Employeeid` is primary key and employee id is foreign key for rest of classes)

2) `EmployeeFamilyTable.cs`

3) `previousEmployeement.cs`

4) `employeeaddress.cs`

5) `employeeEducation.cs`

Each class contains respective properties. Now what I want is to do for each class. I have created 5 views to enter data and each view contain submit button to go to next view.

My problem is I want to save all models at once when I click finish button in last view

please understand problem once am using `mvc 4`

(Answer posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137695/save-multiple-views-model-data-at-once-in-mvc) is closely related to this one, but not working. I am getting error in view )

```
Line 13: { 
Line 14:     
Line 15:    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>ViewBag.FirstStepModel)
Line 16:    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondStepProp)
Line 17:
```

`Compiler Error Message: CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`

I'm stuck, and really need help. Thanks

Comment: In the previous question you need to create separate view models for each step and then serialize the previous model values into a hidden form field. [Darin's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402628/multi-step-registration-process-issues-in-asp-net-mvc-splitted-viewmodels-sing/6403485#6403485) explains it in detail

Comment: Please share code..?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question. You can't ask another question telling people to look at and answer your previous question.

Comment: What do you mean _Please share code?_. I gave you the like. Do you expect me to write it out again